# Quotation mark showing instead of figure

Tags: babel, includegraphics

I have the following code that I compile using pdflatex

```
\documentclass[12pt,brazil]{article}
%   options include 12pt or 11pt or 10pt
%   classes include article, report, book, letter, thesis

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}

\title{MEA Lista 6}
\author{Jo\~ao Guilherme Ferreira Campos}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{plot6.eps}
  \label{1a}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

but the figure does not show up and a quotation mark appears instead. It gives an overfull warning

```
Overfull \vbox (12.0pt too high) has occurred while \output is active (./exam.aux) )
```

but I am not sure how it is related to the problem. I've noticed a few strange things.

a) If I add text to the document the figure appears, but the same error shows in another article where there is text and I would like to understand why the error occurs here to be able to correct it in other files.

b) If I comment the \usepackage[portuguese]{babel} the figure appears, but I need the label of the figure to be in portuguese. Therefore, I need the babel package.

Could anyone please tell me what is going on?

**EDIT**

I corrected the error by adding the package

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You need `\usepackage{epstopdf}` to convert the `eps` file on-the-fly to `pdf`. Moreover, make sure that the image fits vertically on the page (together with the caption). When you say `width=\textwidth`, then the image fits the width, but may still be too high; the warning `overfull vbox` points into this direction. Try a smaller width and see whether it works. Otherwise, we need to see more details. Your document works fine for me when adding some `eps` file.

Comment: @gernot Thank you for your help. However, it was not necessary to do the corrections you suggested. I corrected the error by adding \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}. I realized that this package was necessary when I read the log file and found the error "Missing character: There is no ü in font cmr12!". The funny thing is that before I format the computer I didn't need this package to compile the document, but now I need. Do you have any idea why?